# submitting a base64 .zip encoded file to Judge API

Tags: base64, judge-api

I am trying to submit a simple piece of code the [JudgeAPI](https://ce.judge0.com/#top). When do so I get a response back that reads.

```
{
    "stdout": null,
    "time": "0.002",
    "memory": 588,
    "stderr": "/bin/bash: run.sh: No such file or directory\n",
    "token": "39faf8a5-54ee-4588-b9b4-cca2dcf553c8",
    "compile_output": null,
    "message": "Exited with error status 127",
    "status": {
        "id": 11,
        "description": "Runtime Error (NZEC)"
    }
}
```

The documentation states I need to add a `compile.sh` and a `run.sh` file which I did.

> For the Judge0 to know how to compile and execute your multi-file
> program you need to provide two special files that should be available
> in the root of the .zip archive that you are sending with
> additional_files attribute. These files should be named compile and
> run, and are expected to be Bash scripts that know how to compile and
> execute your multi-file program.

The `run.sh` file is there.

My base64 result is below and can be decoded [here](https://base64.guru/converter/decode/file). Has anyone else had this issue?

```
UEsDBBQAAAAAAINggVYAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALACAAanVkZ2UtdGVzdC9VVA0AB5cBKGSXAShklwEoZHV4CwABBPUBAAAEFAAAAFBLAwQUAAgACACDYIFWAAAAAAAAAADcAAAAFQAgAF9fTUFDT1NYLy5fanVkZ2UtdGVzdFVUDQAHlwEoZJcBKGSdAShkdXgLAAEE9QEAAAQUAAAAY2AVY2dgYmDwTUxW8A9WiFCAApAYAycQGwHxKiAG8e8wEAUcQ0KCoEyQjilA7IGmhBEhzp+cn6uXWFCQk6qXm5icAxRkZRBx3nxorpbf02kLEmSOiL59T5y96AAAUEsHCP9Mw8RdAAAA3AAAAFBLAwQUAAgACAAnRmRWAAAAAAAAAAAeAQAAEQAgAGp1ZGdlLXRlc3QvZ28ubW9kVVQNAAf79wJkmfgCZPv3AmR1eAsAAQT1AQAABBQAAAB1jcESgiAYhM/xFBzzICBW+joIv0iJECJpTx/esplmTzvz7X7WqWUErE0clo5IZ+l9URoQ0g5XhDOEAjwXEwCf0emLmmOAKIdAI8zR9BtOFWkJz4wbxaSJC5quFFZhfb5PjOSUnHHOLhXnVX275gq3tmlq1UvBUPHPpEQCqQeqXTl7eO2iHEwpNpPKuIwH3Ft4i6B2XJm+H023L7L9Z+H8QxMz0U3YkaQapzpDx9sCfQBQSwcIYy3jEbEAAAAeAQAAUEsDBBQACAAIAE9egVYAAAAAAAAAAAQYAAAUACAAanVkZ2UtdGVzdC8uRFNfU3RvcmVVVA0AB2b+J2Rx/idkZv4nZHV4CwABBPUBAAAEFAAAAO2YOw7CMBBEZ40LSzQuKd1wAG5gRckJuAAFV6D30SHaEbIUUlAlgnmS9VaKf2kcTwDY8LhfgAwgwY0zPpLYFoSuNs4hhBBCiH1jrnTcdhtCiB0ynw+FrnRzG58HOnZjMl3oSje3sV+gI53oTBe60s3NQ8sYPowrGxOKMYVYoetXryzE33Bw5fn7P2E1/wshfhiL43Uc8A4Eyw6vduvqhvVLQPCfhadubKEr3dy6CAixFU9QSwcIagCIbbIAAAAEGAAAUEsDBBQACAAIAE9egVYAAAAAAAAAAHgAAAAfACAAX19NQUNPU1gvanVkZ2UtdGVzdC8uXy5EU19TdG9yZVVUDQAHZv4nZHH+J2SdAShkdXgLAAEE9QEAAAQUAAAAY2AVY2dgYmDwTUxW8A9WiFCAApAYAycQGwGxGxCD+BVAzABT4SDAgAM4hoQEQZkVMF3oAABQSwcIC4jAODUAAAB4AAAAUEsDBBQACAAIACdGZFYAAAAAAAAAAEMPAAARACAAanVkZ2UtdGVzdC9nby5zdW1VVA0AB/v3AmT79wJk+/cCZHV4CwABBPUBAAAEFAAAALWXWa+iTBqA7+dX9L3xUFVsVZPMhSLuuyDiHRTFjuwi/PrBMxej55vu0+l8ExITTXyeetdSL6j82v6gacI51p1Rz+e8dFhmrPlxhx/wA/RvP5LU+eHDfy5lE5vUQNvAL73knHLJnY9HTcyV0W4rBOt5eCoXAyrOefyvf3jfgOGTeA9JyNXQzm93RXWXu0b3q3g3OuYlPyiiuWlCPjQNTScy/Q3i33DULGGdVThPsBO4bhzYTzb4AE+oMBk3ExVsZ+0hHc/t9cHcNyd9nyob4yiO1W4RcS6Mr/bosPk96MuBg9VclqN06psPbQUzerxFqyh3tdQrbU/2rtuzKZTHiXnlhDd2WRWson7BpXb4+HEHX0o2n0YmgdJiOigaZ+JuRtFZ3lVNnY/PXaHi2VGaTR+DRn1s1F9jhTeseZ8vQNgiP92E44FuNHcZnpcHEpQnutI4LV9259OpwsRsfo0V37H+oEoFrJYz1TVraz7pLnuq8g9fix4yr/qJMtMzdefFq/R/YytWVoHbPtMrv/WDNM1xeqRHkS+KlgDQbfJleDwGj6K58KsLkRDnc0YTVsz7lozfztxuw7kn6OktiMvSuOLAOoVwpxTcfX5j0f4YpbtB5Gz0wUb/DTJ6Igc+z59Duj7vJ/Nq52S6Uk8HsneqZ3w7W7hVuYfmfRr41RL/DvLlsA1a75XFqjGak2uijjk1GETMX6b5jFbBeYFIKrld0cr1e5e1dXDrMbGTWEX0xKK37PL+BXudWbfn0bV8xGBz9GbaUk0O4yndaplv+sRh1DzZ8hObxtbN+0gLj3twtGizKn12Qv8MEYAE8AAjBGWIhxRhgWcAOsR6DcIJtx5VC8gpQBwpkQeDtRssdVHNJHjQo5mB88wpywUYNN/aIICwfxV5cYhlh2LiAiiKb/UNvKlO7vm8MwMV68l9xagVqcvQuRkhH4YCIfFtSiNXWXxjQwBIqA+NlxA/lEUbYdzLLEpebOtusd8c3Haz9f3Z3tcjc1eKq2wt6LhYr1hyge1s7U88vUq/2NjDSrKYvegQEOCnTuzfMgnLMu+41PpcZa03GZC9NScLt7vqU8jDxSMJLrPo0dVbLsv8Sdj5aG3iLf5jz0tYg9aK9rG4OpLloC1dfTuamI2qiznLQ30nyHwziaqJ8NiYX0v2BPQq/m3mSnAoQzhSKsL2Gedv2mzDu7HgXvOjaiwbx5youX8Mrld99AV3Y9VbswlAQDzioThktmhTW4QusvgXVUXms8rF8932ITINFdVNziWm5QvFzPXzbVXyVT8+/CGLvW9U0mcHICAPeRsIEmSMYvG19p2oHM+apiWjpSTLWrdez/QBsMP9DqyjercOBE6cVUuj5MpfqXoZQBDwooDI0BWxKAiAt4gsvCYwwwmYzwcpzuegaS6NeS2wduJ3gZSCQppRBk+nRzzJa/2Lqmxv9D2DiAdIwBAMYd8FfP8RoiJ+cR0fG4814nnZtxYTuXCpqWLNwiw8xzvGBV0xlsEydWVkbX7p+owLQAnwPBpKsgsky4V9zcjf5CrfwkJQhH0CBTJ0gA2h7VgWxdaL6qTt8eQ+aSnnLEQba6Jf+lUUngaqgLRbW24Vfe+ENJj55jeq/0xPX7Eh6UcHyTwPCHFeVD7chgZl5HJczw5qachNttoq4YxMqm2sxOd6ulavzmRrq18b403Vdx/p64NFGUlD12EOlYEtSNj9W1QVe1R/ndRtvsGqvtOhcAujJe/mG2OQUWnt3Bo/4BZh1swruW3rZnf4Ke91HMVrSrnDsVqdje7g76rx5rmZJ9lUCood6Qh+TChLy3oW/IWXpvFr3jEgUO4TTyAaEuBaEkYUWRJ7kd3krVI7dMzd1O5xniVre2KYYuYa2jofUwWtrlLYmveNkHwnI89bBvVjIopDRLALqA0xhq8ye4BU0RmZ/qW5XJvqdpX0UT5eIDxgiCYkrSLgGM5lPlK/bv4vMvS80xDEfRvJQ8gkRh3BdqH9WhaWXJVDWtiKLtxLTXB3xn23v3QCM2BzNYR9MolIvWaxmX1doA9WFGnx3sDy87YW+y4eWgSLDi8A2bLkF92CEzuJ4PJGVhbW2JKSzapIdd3Nx2OrNsJDvl6i3d5NTPC97vPKFvqn3zj9vhYky3Ewwf8fXT8zuB9Q3NvgUGSUEBfzluvCP9dlkffR/5qiPqPRxx2+hCZBBDDEkEd9lwAHiQz1ciB+Xti+cvZaRUghOysWqq6xzE6gGJwmqUR4exmfnTieVSpbbf5M8hKQkkqBfV6OutvIWkR5hv1aa+LlQbn2Xw9Tl6P2Vjgbotm9BtRaSfxx53/c+f/mjn/uNQREOCQukiRmESbL9EW1Euo2kjt5rKj7vJbUgSIJpnuH9CBHnVwsrvdAT7YD1VM3P1N9/pF0H+eEm3WjTjXy9by+02pB4OpEfH+bJMYuNWpw0czlSVZGP+X86bH+DVBLBwg6+R5jLAcAAEMPAABQSwMEFAAIAAgAWF+BVgAAAAAAAAAAGAAAABEAIABqdWRnZS10ZXN0L3J1bi5zaFVUDQAHWAAoZFkAKGRYAChkdXgLAAEE9QEAAAQUAAAAU1bUT8rM009KLM7g4krPVyhJLS5R0C3jAgBQSwcI7revJhoAAAAYAAAAUEsDBBQACAAIAFhfgVYAAAAAAAAAABQBAAAcACAAX19NQUNPU1gvanVkZ2UtdGVzdC8uX3J1bi5zaFVUDQAHWAAoZFkAKGSdAShkdXgLAAEE9QEAAAQUAAAAY2AVY2dgYmDwTUxW8A9WiFCAApAYAycQGwHxIyAG8hlFGIgCjiEhQRAWWMceII5AU8IEFRdgYJBKzs/VSywoyEnVy0ksLiktTk1JSSxJVQ4Ihqo9A8QeDAz8CHW5ick5QMHkf+opYFvWzeMA0awMzdud9zGv9y+dw/SEZwPTxXji3IsOAFBLBwhP/2oLhQAAABQBAABQSwMEFAAIAAgAvF6BVgAAAAAAAAAAAgEAABIAIABqdWRnZS10ZXN0L21haW4uZ29VVA0ABzT/J2Q2/ydkNP8nZHV4CwABBPUBAAAEFAAAAF2PMQrDMAxFZ+sUwlO8xHugY+eW3sAExQmV7eDIIVB69zokUNrpD3q8/zW7/uk8YXBTBJjCnLJgA0oPQTTU9Ild9G3K3m6WNhdmJrtInqIvMrEGAzCU2OP1uD1opbxQszouhAdozsQXKGvxVmQu0mFiphFUpqWwYHfBr7b90ZgdkpIjHiy8z859dWN27Vfyt0OPxJx0XanqS+29NgjH5uBNNX0AUEsHCC/WDCakAAAAAgEAAFBLAwQUAAgACAC8XoFWAAAAAAAAAACwAAAAHQAgAF9fTUFDT1NYL2p1ZGdlLXRlc3QvLl9tYWluLmdvVVQNAAc0/ydkNv8nZJ0BKGR1eAsAAQT1AQAABBQAAABjYBVjZ2BiYPBNTFbwD1aIUIACkBgDJxAbAXEdEIP4GxiIAo4hIUFQJkjHAiAWQFPCiBCXSs7P1UssKMhJ1ctJLC4pLU5NSUksSVUOCAYpTPvKlAKiyz4rioNoAFBLBwgN09LkXAAAALAAAABQSwMEFAAIAAgA8qgvVgAAAAAAAAAACwIAABcAIABqdWRnZS10ZXN0L21haW5fdGVzdC5nb1VUDQAHCV3EYzD+J2Rr9QJkdXgLAAEE9QEAAAQUAAAAlVHLasMwEDxbX7H4ZBcj3w05lfxAmlspQVXXD2pLjrROU4r/vbuu41JyqkAgZnZndkejse+mQRhM55TqhtEHgkwlKWGkzjWp4nfTUTu9auuHMlJAsm0oF77+LAOepy5gqnKl6slZODJxOuAFQ8SM4GEV0sccvljsYgII9GgiRtjB8wtLTpaYTBJnBgQ5jHEPIx/G0V8EryNawrcNmaVT7tJeLdXp00LyWjwsxrQQWrRW2vc9tj/oTa+CtMW+9ws6F//XpIh0Jymrbooz71/7AKcCyEK1g2AcZ/8bhwSUkD5MLiOrxboACfUuRzZpPInE/mqGscctcKtv7rlUrd+j9+fJ9BmJsZaZC+B+qZj532SwWX0DUEsHCLSPGKQUAQAACwIAAFBLAwQUAAgACADyqC9WAAAAAAAAAACwAAAAIgAgAF9fTUFDT1NYL2p1ZGdlLXRlc3QvLl9tYWluX3Rlc3QuZ29VVA0ABwldxGMw/idknQEoZHV4CwABBPUBAAAEFAAAAGNgFWNnYGJg8E1MVvAPVohQgAKQGAMnEBsBcR0Qg/gbGIgCjiEhQVAmSMcCIBZAU8KIEJdKzs/VSywoyEnVy0ksLiktTk1JSSxJVQ4IBinM/sqUAqJzLNUlQTQAUEsHCA4h5wFcAAAAsAAAAFBLAQIUAxQAAAAAAINggVYAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALACAAAAAAAAAAAADtQQAAAABqdWRnZS10ZXN0L1VUDQAHlwEoZJcBKGSXAShkdXgLAAEE9QEAAAQUAAAAUEsBAhQDFAAIAAgAg2CBVv9Mw8RdAAAA3AAAABUAIAAAAAAAAAAAAO2BSQAAAF9fTUFDT1NYLy5fanVkZ2UtdGVzdFVUDQAHlwEoZJcBKGSdAShkdXgLAAEE9QEAAAQUAAAAUEsBAhQDFAAIAAgAJ0ZkVmMt4xGxAAAAHgEAABEAIAAAAAAAAAAAAKSBCQEAAGp1ZGdlLXRlc3QvZ28ubW9kVVQNAAf79wJkmfgCZPv3AmR1eAsAAQT1AQAABBQAAABQSwECFAMUAAgACABPXoFWagCIbbIAAAAEGAAAFAAgAAAAAAAAAAAApIEZAgAAanVkZ2UtdGVzdC8uRFNfU3RvcmVVVA0AB2b+J2Rx/idkZv4nZHV4CwABBPUBAAAEFAAAAFBLAQIUAxQACAAIAE9egVYLiMA4NQAAAHgAAAAfACAAAAAAAAAAAACkgS0DAABfX01BQ09TWC9qdWRnZS10ZXN0Ly5fLkRTX1N0b3JlVVQNAAdm/idkcf4nZJ0BKGR1eAsAAQT1AQAABBQAAABQSwECFAMUAAgACAAnRmRWOvkeYywHAABDDwAAEQAgAAAAAAAAAAAApIHPAwAAanVkZ2UtdGVzdC9nby5zdW1VVA0AB/v3AmT79wJk+/cCZHV4CwABBPUBAAAEFAAAAFBLAQIUAxQACAAIAFhfgVbut68mGgAAABgAAAARACAAAAAAAAAAAAD/gVoLAABqdWRnZS10ZXN0L3J1bi5zaFVUDQAHWAAoZFkAKGRYAChkdXgLAAEE9QEAAAQUAAAAUEsBAhQDFAAIAAgAWF+BVk//aguFAAAAFAEAABwAIAAAAAAAAAAAAP+B0wsAAF9fTUFDT1NYL2p1ZGdlLXRlc3QvLl9ydW4uc2hVVA0AB1gAKGRZAChknQEoZHV4CwABBPUBAAAEFAAAAFBLAQIUAxQACAAIALxegVYv1gwmpAAAAAIBAAASACAAAAAAAAAAAACkgcIMAABqdWRnZS10ZXN0L21haW4uZ29VVA0ABzT/J2Q2/ydkNP8nZHV4CwABBPUBAAAEFAAAAFBLAQIUAxQACAAIALxegVYN09LkXAAAALAAAAAdACAAAAAAAAAAAACkgcYNAABfX01BQ09TWC9qdWRnZS10ZXN0Ly5fbWFpbi5nb1VUDQAHNP8nZDb/J2SdAShkdXgLAAEE9QEAAAQUAAAAUEsBAhQDFAAIAAgA8qgvVrSPGKQUAQAACwIAABcAIAAAAAAAAAAAAKSBjQ4AAGp1ZGdlLXRlc3QvbWFpbl90ZXN0LmdvVVQNAAcJXcRjMP4nZGv1AmR1eAsAAQT1AQAABBQAAABQSwECFAMUAAgACADyqC9WDiHnAVwAAACwAAAAIgAgAAAAAAAAAAAApIEGEAAAX19NQUNPU1gvanVkZ2UtdGVzdC8uX21haW5fdGVzdC5nb1VUDQAHCV3EYzD+J2SdAShkdXgLAAEE9QEAAAQUAAAAUEsFBgAAAAAMAAwAsgQAANIQAAAAAA==
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with JudgeAPI, but the documentation that you quote states that you need to include "two special files that should be available **in the root** of the .zip archive". However, when I decode your base64 string and open the zip file, there is a directory `judge-test` and the `run.sh` file is inside that directory, so not in the root of the zip file.

Comment: @Marijn. Thank you for pointing that out. I just placed the `judge-test` directory inside a new directory called `judge` and added the `run.sh` to the root of the `judge` directory and sadly got the same result. Looks like I need to play with it some more.

Comment: But why do you place it in a directory at all? It seems like you should zip only the files and not any directory above it.

Comment: @Marijn... Correct. I was able to get past that error. `go: command not found`. is the new one. Thanks for the hint.